# last border-left doesn't display correctly

Tags: html, css

My problem is that in the `nav`, The last `border-left` of `li` doesn't display correctly, i don't know why.
can someone help me to fix that

screenshot of my problem (last left border missing)  :

[image: Border missing]

This is my code :

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
 blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn,
 em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
 b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
 table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas,
 details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav,
 output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
 menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* END RESET */
/*  *{
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
 } */

nav{
 clear: both; /* faire un clear pour revenir a la ligne  */
 width: 960px;
 height: 50px;
 
/*  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 background-color: #3b7c33; */
 
  /* Fallback */
  
     border-radius: 30px;  /* dora 3la kolchi   /*
 /* couleur degradé   /*
 /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5fae53), to(#3b7c33)); 
 /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33); 
 /* Firefox 3.6+ */
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
 /* IE 10+ */
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
 /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
 
 border: 1px solid #336c2b;
 

}
nav ul li 
{
 float:left;
 border-right:1px solid #539948;
 border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
}

nav ul li a{
 display: block; 
 padding: 0 30px;
 height: 50px;  
 line-height: 50px; 
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #387031;
 }
nav ul li a:hover{
 
 background: #5fae53;
 }
nav ul li.home{
 background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%; 
 text-indent: -9999px;
 border-left: none;

 }

nav ul li.home a:hover{
 /* -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
 */
 
 border-top-left-radius: 30px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; 
    background: #5fae53 url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

nav ul li.last{
 
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='header-wrap'>
        <header>


            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Testimonials</a></li>


                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
</div>
```

The code in  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esmnf7um/)

Thanks by advance

Comment: I don't see the leftmost li (Home) at all.  Is that the actual issue, or just a mistake in the fiddle CSS?

Comment: The last border left is display. Just need a border right to the last li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add the following to your cssc

```css
li:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #336c2b;
}
```

Comment: `nav ul li:last-child`
This selector will choose the last li of the nav ul.  Yonatan's answer will choose the last li of the whole page

Comment: Dominofoe is right... Ofcourse you should you the most specific selector for your needs..pay attention - it looks like your border compound from two borders , right and left from each li beside the last li. That's why it looks a little bit different

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from `nav ul li.home`

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

**See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0u09qjc/)**

Comment: no i was make text-indent to place the logo of the home there, this is not what i am looking for i will add a screenshot of what i am looking to fix

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your borders between `li` are composed by the right border of you firts `li` and the left border of the fallow it, so the last `li` only have the right border, so you have to add an element that have the left border. Adding only the right border `border-right: 1px solid #539948;` or the left border `border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;` like others you will not have the exactly same separator that in the others.

[image]

To achieve the exactly separator try one of this:

**1-** Using a pseudo element:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* END RESET */

/*  *{
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
 } */
 nav {
    clear: both;
    /* faire un clear pour revenir a la ligne  */
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    /*  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 background-color: #3b7c33; */
    /* Fallback */
    border-radius: 30px;
    /* dora 3la kolchi   /*
 /* couleur degradé   /*
 /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5fae53), to(#3b7c33));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* IE 10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    border: 1px solid #336c2b;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #539948;
    border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
}

nav ul:after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     border-right: 0;
     height: 50px;
     border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #387031;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #5fae53;
}
nav ul li.home {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-left: none;
}
nav ul li.home a:hover {
    /* -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
 */
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background: #5fae53 url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
nav ul li.last {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='header-wrap'>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="#" title="">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Testimonials</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

**2-** Adding a virtual li at end

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* END RESET */

/*  *{
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
 } */
 nav {
    clear: both;
    /* faire un clear pour revenir a la ligne  */
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    /*  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 background-color: #3b7c33; */
    /* Fallback */
    border-radius: 30px;
    /* dora 3la kolchi   /*
 /* couleur degradé   /*
 /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5fae53), to(#3b7c33));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* IE 10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
    border: 1px solid #336c2b;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #539948;
    border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
}

nav ul li:last-of-type {
     border-right: 0;
     height: 50px;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #387031;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #5fae53;
}
nav ul li.home {
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border-left: none;
}
nav ul li.home a:hover {
    /* -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
 */
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background: #5fae53 url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
nav ul li.last {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='header-wrap'>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="#" title="">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Testimonials</a>

                </li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

I really recommend you "**1-** Using a pseudo element:" to avoid the needless `li` in the html.

Comment: can you specify exactly what you had changed in my code and thanks

Comment: @TH3AWAK3NING I update my answer to explain you what I change and I added an img to show you. Let mi know if this don't works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it simple and add a `box-shadow`. It will show on last or will mix with next left border.

If nav bar breaks into lines you won't have to mind wich right border could go missing visually :)

```
nav ul li 
{
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #539948;
    border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 #336c2b;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esmnf7um/1/

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* END RESET */

/*  *{
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
 } */

nav {
  clear: both;
  /* faire un clear pour revenir a la ligne  */
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  /*  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 background-color: #3b7c33; */
  /* Fallback */
  border-radius: 30px;
  /* dora 3la kolchi   /*
 /* couleur degradé   /*
 /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#5fae53), to(#3b7c33));
  /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
  /* IE 10+ */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5fae53, #3b7c33);
  border: 1px solid #336c2b;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #539948;
  border-left: 1px solid #336c2b;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 #336c2b;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #387031;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #5fae53;
}
nav ul li.home {
  background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-left: none;
}
nav ul li.home a:hover {
  /* -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
 */
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background: #5fae53 url(images/home.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
nav ul li.last {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='header-wrap'>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#" title="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```